# How to set full control to a directory?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following simple code to add full control to a directory, but it doesn't work.

```
        String dir_name = @"folder_full_path";
        DirectorySecurity dir_security = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir_name);
        FileSystemAccessRule access_rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(@"AccountName",
            FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(access_rule);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(dir_name, dir_security);
```

But this code only set **special permissions** to the target folder. This code is almost the same as the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx). I am scratching my head for a reasonable explanation... Hope someone could shed some light on me.

Many thanks.

Comment: What if you used the 5-parameter constructor for FileSystemAccessRule instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ben. I could get it done with the 5-parameter constructor now. But I don't know why the 3-parameter constructor exists if it just WON'T work?

Answer (score 14):

After some reverse Engineering of the original ACL rules I got it to work with the following code:

```
IdentityReference everybodyIdentity = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);

FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    everybodyIdentity,
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow);
```

May it helps any further visitor :)

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the 5-parameter version.

Comment: +1 for the WellKnownSidType.  I need the Administrator account in my program.

Comment: Yup, MSDN example does not work, but the 5 parameter method does.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score -4):

:) Turn around.

- Make a directory.
- Assign Permissions.
- Read DirectorySecurity ACL and check in the debugger how it looks ;)

Voila.